# Twilio studio messing up the json when sending an HTTP request

Tags: json, twilio, twilio-api

using twilio studio we receive sms message to one of out twilio numbers and we send it to one of our services.
we send it using the `MAKE HTTP REQUEST` widget with the CONTENT TYPE: json
in there we have the following body:

```json
{
  "Body":"{{trigger.message.Body}}",
  "From":"{{trigger.message.From}}"
}
```

but when an sms message with new lines is received
for example somthing like

```
hello name
how are you
```

then the json twilio studio sends ends up looking like this

```json
{
  "Body":"hello name
how are you",
  "From":"some number"
}
```

and we end up getting `Unexpected token \n in JSON`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using the following:

```
{
“Body”: "{{ trigger.message.Body | newline_to_br | replace: "<br />", " " | strip_newlines }}",
“From”: "{{trigger.message.From}}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Twilio Studio you can use Liquid Syntax to fix this.

```
{
 "Body":"{{trigger.message.Body | strip_newlines}}",
 "From":"{{trigger.message.From}}"
}
```

There are lots of Liquid Syntax filters available in Twilio Studio!
See e.g. https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/liquid-template-language